# Json Object Size Limitation Android

Tags: android, json

i have one big question, please suggest me what is the maximum responded (Server response) json object recommended size for android device ?

I have json Object size is 15 mb approximately, Is it Good for Android Mobile for analysis ???

Ya its required small json object for analysis for performance issue ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Not Better Solution to Get Response of !5 mb .

if You Done This Then So many Issue Ocure like **OutofMemory**

other is Like **Long Execution Time**

user inherit From your app cause of **Long waiting delay**

thats y  my suggestion is that you have to use pagination or load more data and retrive very samll json

Comment: is this limitation is still same or any change with latest OS/http libraries that we use?